# Python Calculating Business Days Between Two Dates when the end date may be blank

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

Figured out how to calculate business days from various posts, but not how to address missing end dates. The file from which the dataframe is generated is a .txt file from an ancient database. The pattern of the file is: EmpID, Name, StartDt, EndDt. For this reason I am including how the .txt file is brought into the dataframe in the code below. Someone may have a better idea how to handle the data types or that may be the problem.
The goal is to add a column with DaysToCmplt using the StartDt and EndDt. The problem occurs when the EndDt is blank.

The error occurs on this row (the code works fine if there are no missing dates):

df['DaysToCmplt'] = (df.apply(lambda row: len(pd.bdate_range(row['StartDt'], row['CompleteDt'])), axis=1))-1

Exception has occurred: ValueError
Neither `start` nor `end` can be NaT

I have also tried creating a definition (TAT) and passing the Start and End Dates with this error, that occurs within the definition:

Exception has occurred: TypeError
Cannot convert input [0   2023-03-01

```
#lots of import statements here

def getCompDataFromFile():
    colspecsvalues = (
        (0, 9),
        (10, 34),
        (35, 45),
        (46, 56)
    )
    col_names = [
        "EmpID",
        "Name",
        "StartDt",
        "CompleteDt"
    ]
    col_conv = {
        "EmpID": conv_str,
        "Name": conv_str,
        "StartDt": conv_str,
        "CompleteDt": conv_str
    }

    df = pd.read_fwf(r'path to file',
                     colspecs=colspecsvalues, names=col_names, converters=col_conv)
    
    df['StartDt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDt'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
    df['CompleteDt'] = df.CompleteDt.apply(lambda x: get_Cmplt_Date(x))
    df['DaysToCmplt'] = (df.apply(lambda row:len(pd.bdate_range(row['StartDt'],row['CompleteDt'])), axis=1))-1
    #df['DaysToCmplt'] = df.apply(lambda x: TAT(df['StartDt'],df['CompleteDt']))
    print(df)

def conv_str(x):
    if x.replace(' ', '') == '':
        return ' '
    else:
        return str(x)

def get_Cmplt_Date(value):
    value = value.strip()
    if not value:
        return ""
    else:
        value = pd.to_datetime(value, format='%m/%d/%Y')
        return value

def TAT(stvalue,endvalue):
    #define US business days
    us_bus = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
    value = pd.bdate_range(stvalue,endvalue, freq=us_bus)

#start program
DaysToCmplt = getCompDataFromFile()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a bit more of business logic: What does a "blank" end date mean?  Today's date? The date on the file? 60 days after the start date? The start date itself? Something else?

Once you have that, you can use [Series.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) to fix up your strings.  Insert this (or analogous) before you do other processing of the specifc column:

```
today_str = datetime.now().datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
df['CompleteDt'] = df['CompleteDt'].replace('', today_str)
```

If computation of the 'CompleteDt' is more complex, depending on values from multiple columns, you'll probably need a lambda function or similar to what you've written.

If you want to simply skip all records with a blank 'CompleteDt', you can filter those out with either

```
df_complete = df[df['CompleteDt']!='']
```

or

```
df_complete = df[df['CompleteDt'].notna()]
```

depending on how the blank is stored.  Then you could process the complete and incomplete records separately and recombine them.

```
df_incomplete = df[df['CompleteDt']=='']
df_incomplete['DaysToComplete'] = 'Incomplete'
# Insert your calculation of df_complete['DaysToComplete'] here.
full_df = pandas.concat([df_complete, df_incomplete])
```

Comment: Blank means there is nothing returned from the database. This is meant to be used to calculate how many business dys it takes to complete training. If there is no date present in the EndDate that indicates training is incomplete, then the DaysToCmplt column would contain some value such as "Incomplete." Otherwise when both the StartDt and EndDt are present the business days calculation would be End - Start. The problem I am having is whether it is a sigle row of coding or a lamda function is to get Python is not dealing well with a non-existent date.

Comment: @RhettBrindle updated to handle skip-records case

Comment: Finally getting back to this. It works fine for the df_incomplete, but the step to keep the rows with dates fails when I try to isolate the dates in their own dataframe: `df_YesFRD = df[df_YesSD['FirstDate'].notna()]` with error: **pandas.errors.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).**